# Regex to match SQL keywords in C# code

Tags: c#, regex

I am failing to detect SQL in C# code by using Regex.

This is my regex string:

```
(?i)(?s)\b(select)\b(.*?)\b(from)\b|\b(insert)\b(.*?)\b(into)\b|\b(update)\b(.*?)\b(set)\b|\b(delete)(.*?)\b(from)\b
```

I want to match SQL keywords like the following:

```
... SELECT ... FROM ...
... INSERT ... INTO ...
... UPDATE ... SET ...
... DELETE ... FROM ...
```

I am using the following website to test my regular expressions:

http://regexstorm.net/tester

It works just like I expect it to work on the website, but for some random reason, this regex does not work if my code runs.

"Regex.Matches" does not find any matches for some reason.

---

The SQL can all be in one single line, or the SQL can stretch over multiple lines.

So, basically, I am giving my application a directory. This directory contains ".cs" files.

I then read the text in the files, and try to match the above Regex string.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
private string _strRegex = "(?i)(?s)\b(select)\b(.*?)\b(from)\b|\b(insert)\b(.*?)\b(into)\b|\b(update)\b(.*?)\b(set)\b|\b(delete)(.*?)\b(from)\b";

string lines = string.Empty;
bool foundMatch = false;
//Match the text to our regular expression, and see if we find a match anywhere.
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(strFile, _strRegex))
{
    //Get the line number this match occurred at in the file.
    var lineNumber = strFile.Take(match.Index).Count(c => c == '\n') + 1;
    //Get the actual line.
    int lineNum = 0;
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(strFile))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lineNum++; //First, increment!

            if (lineNum == lineNumber)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (!line.StartsWith("//"))
                {
                    foundMatch = true;
                    lines += $@"    [Line {lineNumber}] - {line}{Environment.NewLine}";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

if (foundMatch)
{
    File.AppendAllText(_itemsLogPath, $@"{file}{Environment.NewLine}{lines}{Environment.NewLine}");
}
```

Comment: I assume your CS files do not contain any LINQ expressions, or you are going to get a whole load of false positives.

Comment: _"detect SQL in C# code"_ - why? Anyway read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Phylogenesis - Yes, I do have LINQ in the code, but it is not so much. Also, they wont match because the LINQ expressions is not in the same order as the SQL keyqoeds, eg: "from ... select" for LINQ, etc

Comment: @FrederikMoller Unless there are two LINQ expressions, and the `select` from the first is matched with the `from` in the second.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I want to do this, because other developers have put sql code in our frontend. I want to identify these files, and move the code to the proper project / class

Comment: @FrederikMoller In which case, aren't you better off searching for the various `Execute()` calls, then trying to parse SQL?

Comment: @Phylogenesis - True! But for now, don't worry about that :). the LINQ really is minimal.

Comment: @Phylogenesis - Because the code also has custom methods, so the Execute() search will not return me everything :).

Comment: What happens if you put _strRegex = @".... eg a literal string?

Comment: @BugFinder - YES! Now I am finding matches!!!

Comment: @BugFinder - If you post an answer stating to use @, I will mark it as correct. That is indeed what I needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the \b is being trying to translate into a c# string shortcut, not a regex code, you need to literalise the string.

```
private string _strRegex = @"(?i)(?s)\b(select)\b(.*?)\b(from)\b|\b(insert)\b(.*?)\b(into)\b|\b(update)\b(.*?)\b(set)\b|\b(delete)(.*?)\b(from)\b";
```

that poor little @ makes all the difference

Comment: Almost a whole day trying to figure out why it does not work, and here you come and tell me to add @. Thanx :)!

Comment: I fell for it in the past :p

Answer (score 2):

*The SQL can all be in one single line, or the SQL can stretch over multiple lines.* - I assume that the problem might be at this point.

Try using `RegexOptions` to specify this.
It would look like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"...pattern", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

---

**Edit 1**

As mentioned by [BugFinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687262/bugfinder), .. don't forget about the `@` in front of your pattern string, declaring it as a literal string.

Comment: It it still not finding any matches using this :(. However, you did give me the option to specify the "ignore case" as regex options, I was putting it in the regex string :)

Comment: `RegexOptions.Multiline` is the wrong flag to use in this situation. It stops `.` from matching a newline character.

Comment: @Phylogenesis oh yes you're right, my bad. It's the other way around. I updated the answer accordingly